# formcollection how to access html form associative array

Tags: c#, arrays, associative-array

i try to access a associative array in c#. The Array is send per post to my c# mvc web application.

e. g. html form

```
 <Input Name="myArray[hashKey1]" value="123">
 <Input Name="myArray[hashKey2]" value="456">
```

and in c# i need the keys and values - perhaps with data dictionary?!

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {
    Dictionary<string, string> = KEY, VALUE

     ...
    }
```

i hope you can follow me :-/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can; but you need to specify the method of POST.

This doesn't work:

```
<form id="frmThing" action="@Url.Action("Gah", "Home")">
    <input id="input_a" name="myArray[hashKey1]" value="123" />
    <input id="input_b" name="myArray[hashKey2]" value="456" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

This does:

```
<form id="frmThing" action="@Url.Action("Gah", "Home")" method="POST">
    <input id="input_a" name="myArray[hashKey1]" value="123" />
    <input id="input_b" name="myArray[hashKey2]" value="456" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
```

Edit: To actually access the details in C#, in your example you'd do one of the following:

```
String first = collection[0];
String secnd = collection[1];
```

or

```
String first = collection["myArray[hashKey1]"];
String secnd = collection["myArray[hashKey2]"];
```

or even:

```
foreach (var item in collection) {
    string test = (string)item;
}
```

Edit two:

Here's a trick you can use to get the behavior you want to see.
Firstly, define an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Each(this FormCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (string key in collection.AllKeys)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, collection[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your action result you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Gah(FormCollection vals)
{
    foreach (var pair in vals.Each())
    {
        string key = pair.Key;
        string val = pair.Value;
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: sorry, the problem is not the post. i don't know how to Access the data in c# !

Comment: thank you. sorry again, but i don't know the hashKey1, hasKey2, hashKeyN - but i need the key, too...

Comment: That's worrying - the only way for this to work properly is for you to know the Keyname, after all it should only be specified in your own HTML, so you should have all the knowledge you need? Otherwise, I think there maybe a GetKeys method you can evaluate, but you really should know the name of the input fields.

Comment: Thank you Russ C! I was thinking on something like foreach( $Array as $key => $value ) which is possible in php. But i try to solve it a little different.

Comment: Hi, my updated answer details a new way so you can enumerate the key and value from the collection object.